# visual studio xamarin and mysql crud

Tags: mysql, xamarin, crud

I have not found any example to work with visual studio xamarin with mysql crud using mysql connector.

It would be great to have it, I hope somebody can provide such example.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use MySQL on a mobile device no matter if you write your app with Xamarin and C# or Java or what ever you choose.

The typical solution would be to implement a web service around your database and consume it within your mobile app.

Comment: Actually, I have seen an example on basic4android using the java and mysql connector. But i dont know how go about that. I am hoping on xamarin on visual studio.

Comment: Provide a direct link I won't search for it, because what I have written still applies.